# Unable to locate package libc6-i386 and lib32z1

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I am new to Ubuntu.

I am running Ubuntu Mate 16.04 in a Raspberry PI 3

I need to use Pulse Secure which requires that I install `libc6-i386` and `lib32z1`

Instructions are:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

I get `unable to locate package ..` for both.

I found several old questions in the forums questions however the links no longer work.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This two packages are only available for the amd64 based systems ("normal" 64 bit PCs) but not for armhf like the Raspberry PI 3.

If Pulse Secure requires them it's most likely only available for amd64 and doesn't work on a Raspberry PI.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see the `libc6-i386` package is only available for `amd64` architecture and `lib32z1` is only available for `amd641` and `s390x`.

```
rmadison libc6-i386
 ...
 libc6-i386 | 2.24-9ubuntu2     | artful           | amd64
 libc6-i386 | 2.24-9ubuntu2.2   | zesty-security   | amd64
 libc6-i386 | 2.24-9ubuntu2.2   | zesty-updates    | amd64
```

And:

```
 rmadison lib32z1
 ...
 lib32z1 | 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu1  | zesty           | amd64, s390x
 lib32z1 | 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu1  | artful          | amd64, s390x
```